# Is it possible to make a trigger that does not allow INSERT?

Tags: trigger, insert, transaction, sqlite, rollback

I'm currently learning how to implement sqlite commands through C code and I've been trying to figure out the best way to ensure that no data can be inserted to a table (which will only happen during a certain period of time).

I have a database `History` and in this database exists the table `events` with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE events
    (
     id integer primary key autoincrement, 
     msg varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
     ago varchar(30) NOT NULL
    );
```

I know a mySQL implementation would likely use `INSTEAD OF INSERT` on the table, though I also know `INSTEAD OF` can't be executed on tables, only views in sqlite. (To be honest I'm new to databases so I only *kinda* understand this concept).

Would anyone with some more database experience be able to help me with writing (or at the very least understanding the theory behind) a trigger that does not allow data to be inserted to the table?

Edit: [This](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/02/creating-insert-triggers-silently-ignore-data-dont-want/) article is where I first got the idea that this would be possible

Comment: I'd also be interested in the feasibility of sending a `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, allowing an `INSERT`, and then performing a `ROLLBACK` after

Comment: Have you looked at using a `BEFORE` trigger like in [this example](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-trigger/)? You could simply raise an error on ANY insert.

Comment: Interesting solution, do you know if the warning message would be suppressible?

Comment: @AMtwo  Actually, that's something I can figure out on my own. But your comment solved my problem so if you want to answer I'll accept it

Answer (score -1):

It will be something like

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER forbid_events_update
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
ON events
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    RAISE(ROLLBACK, 'Events update not allowed'); /* maybe ABORT of FAIL */
END;
```

And the same for INSTEAD OF DELETE.

Comment: @mustaccio I have removed the phrase "If your database engine does not allow `INSTEAD OF` triggers on tables, you can use `BEFORE` triggers for the same purpose." which you have added into the answer. The question is tagged as SQLite-relative, so INSTEAD OF triggers are available.